# I want to copy the currently running script to startup in python

Tags: python

I have a python script, and I want to copy it to startup, or download a file and copy it to startup when it runs. How would I do this? It would also be preferable if it only did it if the file didn't exist in startup, but either way is fine. Can someone help?

Comment: What OS are you targeting? If Linux, which distro?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: What research have you already done? It seems like there are multiple components to this question: 1) find the startup folder, 2) find the currently running script, 3) preferably, check if the file already exists, 4) copy. There should be existing resources about all of those.